# IBM-MQ's .NET XMS... and Mono?

Tags: .net, mono, ibm-mq

Has anyone tried to use IBM's .NET Websphere client libraries (XMS, etc) on Mono? If so, was it a good (seamless) experience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just installed MonoDevelop IDE and prerequisites Gtk#2.12.x tool kit. Wrote a sample producer application in couple of minutes and it worked fine, successfully put a message onto a queue.

MonoDevelop IDE worked much faster than VS2010 IDE. Experience was good.

Mono is a software platform designed to allow developers to easily create cross platform applications. Are there any specifics that you are looking for? platform compatibility etc?